# Restructure the Terraform variables for scalability

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

Currently I have following variables for my Terraform project

```
repos = ["Test:Repo1","Test:Repo2","Dev:Repo3","Prod:Repo4"]
Proj = "Proj1"
```

I also have a repo configuration code as given below

```
resource "git_repository" "repo" {
  count      =length(var.repos)
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = element(split(":", var.repos[count.index]), 1)
  initialization {
   init_type = "Clean"
  }
```

Here I'm specifying the name of repo by using `element()` and `split()` function by giving a delimiter `:`. The reason why I'm passing  the value in the format `ENV:REPO` is because I want to use this `ENV` in a null resource while running a batch script . Now I want to pass the group name also as an input in the current list. But I really don't want to pass it as  another string with the delimiter `ENV:REPO:GROUP`. So I'm planning to restructure  in a way so that I can include all the values and in future if any new input came then I need to include those too.

Above mentioned list is an example and I will keep on adding more values when I want to add a new repo. What is the best way to restructure the above variables?

Comment: @Marcin I started using map(objects) as my variable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering using `map` instead of lists. Maybe something as the following would be a good start:

```
variable "projects" {
    default = {
        "Proj1" = {
            "Test" = ["Repo1", "Repo2"]
            "Dev" =  ["Repo3", "Repo4"]
        }
    }
}
```